# react js nodejs socket.io

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have a problem connecting to my front end server socket on my back end
in my front end ( react ) i have this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Form,FormGroup, Label, Input, Button, Alert} from 'reactstrap';
import Header from '../../components/header';
import io from 'socket.io-client';
export default class Login extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        console.log(this.props);
        this.state = {
            message: this.props.location.state?this.props.location.state.message: '',
        };
    }

    signIn = () => {
        let socket = null;

            async function connect () {
               socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080/');
            }
            connect();

    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="col-md-6">
                <Header title="ReactJS Login"/>
                <hr className="my-3"/>

                    <Button color="primary" onClick={this.signIn}> Entrar </Button>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

in my back end:

```
const usersRouter = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const postRouter = require('./routes/post');
const matchRouter = require('./routes/matchRoutes');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

const socket = require('socket.io');

const server = app.listen(
  port,
  console.log(`Server running in ${process.env.NODE_ENV} mode on port ${port}`)
  );

let io = require('socket.io')(server);
app.set("io", io);

io.on('connection', socket => {
   require('./routes/socket')(socket);
});
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
  });''
app.use(express.json());
app.use('/', router);


module.exports = app;
```

in my router folder i have this:

```
const socketController = require ('../controllers/SocketController');
module.exports = (socket) => {
    socket.on('myevent', (message) => {
            console.log('bateu aq');
           socket.emit('myEvent', {message: 'hello world'});
    });
 };
```

I am also wondering how I could add a jwt validate middleware to my route that I have

I also don't know if this is the best code structure I can have to work with socket using routes and controllers, if anyone can help me how to improve it.

Comment: What is the actual problem/error?

Comment: When I click my button nothing happens and doesn't connect to my socket

Comment: You def connectin to the correct port on your local machine? Can you set a breakpoint in `io.on('connection', socket => {` and see if the client is connecting

Comment: yes if i make this : io.on('connection', socket => {
  console.log('xd');
  socket.emit('myEvent', {message: 'hello world'});
});                                                                    //////////                      I can connect to my socket, but using that struct I can't and how could I add middlware?

Comment: Server running in undefined mode on port 8080

Api rodando na porta undefined

Comment: So the client **does** connect and you can see the `io.on('connection'` fire?
`

`

Comment: yes i can pick socket id and etc

Comment: Ok, that's good - I don't see any events being emitted or subscribed to in your react app though?

Comment: Yes I didn't do any events I was just testing, and I couldn't add a middlware that I use to validate my jwt

Comment: It is really difficult to try and determine what you are asking. The question simply says "react js nodejs socket.io" - that is not a question, I can't actually find a question here. You have said that you cannot connect, but have just confirmed you can. You are now asking about middleware. Please take a moment and refine your question so it's clear and we don't have to have endless comments when trying to assist you. It really takes a lot of effort to try and determine what is being asked, and what the actual issue is.

Comment: But I really can't connect when I use: io.on ('connection', socket => {
   require ('./ routes / socket') (socket);
});

Comment: When I use require on my route I can't connect.

Comment: Are you able to set breakpoints in your IDE?

Comment: yes it reaches socket.on ('connection', (message) =>

in my file
socket.js (folder routes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no code in your example that is actually interacting with the server. Please update the code as follows to determine the connections and events are working as per the question comments.

**React:**

```
async function connect () {
    socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080/');

    socket.on('hello', (message) => {
        console.log(message);
    });

    socket.on('myevent', message => {
        console.log(message);
    });

    socket.emit('myevent', {foo: 'bar'});
}
```

**Express:**

```
module.exports = (socket) => {
    socket.emit('hello', {data: 'this is a message'});

    socket.on('myevent', (message) => {
       console.log(message);

       socket.emit('myevent', {message: 'OK'});
    });
 };
```

Comment: now ok thanks,
How can I get middlware before going to this backend code?